# Custom validation on required fields + set focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I would like to add a custom validation on my form, but only for required field (I use a condition in ng-required).

So for instance : If a field is required, I need to check if its value is different of "--". If it is, this field is valid and can continue. Otherwise, the field is invalid, the focus is set on this field and the form is not validated.

I have created a directive :

```
app.directive('validation', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.validation = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (viewValue == null || viewValue == '' || viewValue == '--') {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

But this one is call on all fields (required or not. I need to call it only on non-required fields) :

```
<input validation ng-required="evaluateCondition(field.MandatoryCondition, 'mandatory')" /> <!-- evaluateCondition returns false, so don't call the special validation -->

<input validation ng-required="evaluateCondition(field.MandatoryCondition, 'mandatory')" /> <!-- evaluateCondition returns true, so call the special validation -->
```

And, if the field is required, the custom validation returns false, I need to focus on this field.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why don't you use something already exists? http://nelsonomuto.github.io/angular-ui-form-validation/

Comment: I need to build it by myself and understand exactly how it works